# Setting environment variables for SmartGit to use

Tags: smartgit

I have a pre-commit hook that runs some tests. This used to work great until the tests started to rely on environment variables. Is there a way to set those environment variables in SmartGit so the pre-commit tests can complete?

Answer (score 3):

Two options:

1) Add your variables to `/etc/profile` or `/etc/launchd.conf` and SmartGit will pick them up.

2) Simply launch SmartGit from the shell instead of the desktop environment and your variables from files such as `~/.bashrc` will be present. (That's what I'm doing, using a brief alias for convenience.)

Comment: +1 for the 'easy' fix to start SmartGit from the shell. I had the problem that Node wasn't known in my pre-push hook.

Answer (score 1):

SmartGit will pass all environment variables of its own to the forked `git` process. Hence, if you make sure that SmartGit is started with the correct configuration, your pre-commit hook should work.

Comment: I'm guessing that this isn't happening for me or I've misunderstood your answer. Does SmartGit have a list of environment variables somewhere?

Comment: Check log.txt in the settings directory (see About dialog): immediately after a start, all environment variables with which it was started will be logged. There environment variables will be passed to Git (including some new).

Comment: I see the list that you're talking about in the log file. The ones that I set in my ~/.bashrc file are not in there. Where would I need to set them for SmartGit to pick them up?

Comment: I guess you are invoking `bin/smartgit.sh` to start SmartGit? Then I don't understand why your ~/.bashrc file is not picked up.